# JavaFX TableView with array of TableColumns

Tags: java, javafx

I got a `TableView<MonthRow>` where I want to display each month of the year and its relevant days.

I got those three classes for presentation purposes:

```java
public record DayCell(
        LocalDate date,
        DayType type
) {
    public String nameOfDay() {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
    }
}
```

```java
public enum DayType {
    COMPASSIONATE_LEAVE("C"),
    EMPTY("E"),
    NOT_ON_PAYROLL("N"),
    QUARANTINE("Q"),
    REGULAR_LEAVE("R"),
    SICK_LEAVE("S"),
    TRAINING("TRG"),
    TRAVEL("T"),
    UNPAID_LEAVE("U");

    private final String shortName;

    DayType(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }
}
```

```java
public record MonthRow(
        String name,
        DayCell[] days // amount of days in that specific month
) {
}
```

And then I create the table content:

```java
public ObservableList<MonthRow> createMonth(int year) {
    MonthRow[] months = new MonthRow[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, i + 1, 1);
        months[i] = new MonthRow(date.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH), createCells(date));
    }

    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(months);
}

public DayCell[] createCells(LocalDate date) {
    DayCell[] cells = new DayCell[date.lengthOfMonth()];

    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i] = new DayCell(date.plusDays(i), DayType.EMPTY);
    }

    return cells;
}
```

Having the ObservableList now for the TableView, I am kinda stuck. I want to have one TableColumn for the month and 31 TableColumns for the DayCells. However, because it's an array I am not sure how to reflect the cellData of each DayCell into each TableCell.
Also, because some months do not have 31 days and therefore, the
cells should not show any content for the missing days.

Each cell should show the `nameOfDay()` content and colouring according to the `DayType` (will be done in the respective cellFactory at some point).

[TableView Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl91G.jpg)

This might be a completely wrong approach, so please don't hesitate to guide me towards a different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
TableView<MonthRow> table = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<MonthRow, String> monthColumn = new TableColumn<>("Month");
monthColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getName()));
table.getColumns().add(monthColumn);

for (int i = 0; i < 31 ; i++) {
    TableColumn<MonthRow, DayCell> dayColumn = new TableColumn<>(Integer.toString(i+1));
    final int index = i ;
    dayColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        MonthRow month = cellData.getValue();
        if (index < month.getDays().size()) {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(month.getDays()[index]);
        } else {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
        }
    });
    dayColumn.setCellFactory(new TableCell<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(DayCell day, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(day, empty);
            if (empty | day == null) {
                setText("");
            } else {
                setText(day.nameOfDay());
            }
        }
    });
    table.getColumns().add(dayColumn);
}
```

> This might be a completely wrong approach

Maybe. Do you need the functionality of a `TableView` here? E.g. selection of a month (row), etc? Perhaps a simple `GridPane` inside a `ScrollPane` would be a more convenient approach; it really depends on your project requirements.

Comment: Cheers, exactly what I was trying to achieve. Even made it half way myself :D
And yeah, I was thinking about a GridPane as well but I kinda wanted to achieve this one first to see whether it works to my satisfaction.

Comment: So I managed to make it look like [link](https://gyazo.com/2867c9ebdb350625cd7124835bf5e95b). And because I want to combine/merge same day types to make it look like a calendar, the tableview idea seems to be getting in my way because I'd always have to relate the table cells to the nodes I am displaying. I shall now try the GridPane approach and see.